# In Pyramid, is there any kind of "hook" that occurs just before a view is called?

Tags: hook, pyramid

I have some bits of code I would like to execute just before any/all views are invoked, such as some logging.

Is there a way to do this in Pyramid?

Comment: I have looked at View Derivers, but you have to enable them on a view by view basis, which defeats my purpose of automatically logging a message when each view is invoked, without having to modify the view..

Comment: Not true. A view deriver wraps all views. They wrap each view individually allowing them to accept per-view options and even avoid wrapping specific views, but that's up to their body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the tween [1] and view deriver [2] documentation have examples of timing code. It really depends on what you want to measure and what information you want available to you when you do the measurement. For example the tween doesn't know what view was executed, only the URL. However it encompasses more of the pipeline.

[1] http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/hooks.html#creating-a-tween

[2] http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/hooks.html#custom-view-derivers

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by subscribing to some events.

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/events.html

The one you want is probably `ContextFound`.

You can subscribe either with the decorator (http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/events.html#pyramid.events.subscriber):

```
from pyramid.events import ContextFound
from pyramid.events import subscriber

@subscriber(ContextFound)
def do_something(event):
    print(event)
    print(event.request)
```

Or imperatively with `add_subscriber` (http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.add_subscriber):

```
from pyramid.events import ContextFound

def main(global_config, **settings):
    # rest of your config here
    config.add_subscriber(do_something, ContextFound)

def do_something(event):
    print(event)
    print(event.request)
```